# Citing figures in APA 7th Ed

Tags: citations, graphics

In my thesis I used two figures from a textbook, I included the proper citation under the figures in APA format (i.e. stating the copyright and all that) and I read that I also need to cite them in my reference list. However, the textbook I took them from is already one of my other references and I did not specify pages because I used content from various chapters in the textbook. So in my reference list should I include a separate section for figures which states the same textbook reference and lists the exact page numbers for the figures? Or should I just leave it like this given that I did the proper citation under the figure where it stated the page number along with the textbook? I don't think it's right to include two citations of the same source in your references but I also don't want to plagiarize. I also don't think it's proper APA format to have a separate figures reference section. If somebody could help me out that would be great.